# Find the longest word in a string?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, return

I am trying to write a basic javascript function to find the longest word in a string and log it's length.

So far I have:

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var words = [];
  var longest = [];
  words.push(str.split(" "));
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    if (words[i].length > longest[0].length){
      longest.push(words[i]);
    }
  }
  return longest[0].length;
}

findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog');
```

It makes perfect sense to me, yet it gives me an error. I tried console.logging each step and it fails around the for loop.

Comment: `longest[0].length` fails when `longest` is empty. Also, `unshift` is probably what you want rather than `push` since you're checking the length of `longest[0]`

Comment: `words.push(str.split(" "));` not doing what you think it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `words.push(str.split(" "))`, the array `words` looks like

```
[
    ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]
]
```

Another problem is that when you check `longest[0].length` for the first iteration in the `for`, it is `undefined`. Which results in the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

To solve this, you can use `longest` as `string` instead of `array`. And in the `for`, assign the string having the `length` greater than the current `longest` string to it.

At the end of the function, you can return the `longest` string.

**Problems/Suggestions:**

1. Use `str.split(' ')` to directly assignment to `words` variable
2. Use `longest` as `string` variable instead of `array` and `initialize` it to empty string, i.e. `''`, to avoid the above error
3. Compare the length of the `longest` with the string in the `words` array
4. If the length of the string in `words` array is greater than the `longest`, update the `longest`.
5. Use `\s+` to `split` the string by spaces

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var words = str.split(/\s+/);
  var longest = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > longest.length) {
      longest = words[i];
    }
  }
  return longest;
}

var longestWord = findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog');

document.write('Longest Word: "' + longestWord + '"');
document.write('<br />Longest Word Length: ' + longestWord.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify this using [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Array.prototype.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift). For example

```js
var str = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog',
    longest = str.split(' ').sort(function(a, b) {
                  return b.length - a.length;
              }).shift();

document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = longest;
document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = longest.length;
```

```html
<p id="word"></p>
<p id="length"></p>
```

---

The `sort()` will produce an array of strings sorted by their length (*longest to shortest*) and `shift()` grabs the first element. You could also sort the other way (*shortest to longest*) using `return a.length - b.length` and `pop()` instead of `shift()` to grab the last element.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            longest = str[i].length;
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var arr=str.split(" ");
  var sarr=arr.sort(function(a,b){return b.length-a.length;});
  str=sarr[0];
  return str.length;
}
```

using the javascript `Array.prototype.sort()` we can slove this problem elegantly without using the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (words[i].length > longest[0].length)
```

You will be getting error in above line. As at first time, it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
words.push(str.split(" "));
```

should be

```
words=str.split(" ")
```

And @Tushar solved the rest of your "problems" too ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another shorter version:

```js
function findTheLongestWord(str) {
  var temp = '';
  (str || "").split(/\s+/).forEach(function(word) {
    temp = word.length > temp.length && word || temp;
  });
  return "longest word is: " + temp + " and it's length is: " + temp.length;
}

alert (findTheLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog, once again!"));
```

Answer (score -1):

To find the longest keyword string in Java you need to write a program.

```java
public class FindLarge {

    private String longestWord;

    public String longestWord(String sen) {

        String arr[] = sen.split(" ");      // seperates each word in the string and stores it in array

        longestWord = arr[0];               // Assume first word to be the largest word

        for (String a : arr)
            if (longestWord.length() < a.length())      // check length of each word
                longestWord = a;

        return longestWord;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FindLarge fl=new FindLarge();

        String longestWord=fl.longestWord("Hello Welcome to Java");   // string to be checked

        System.out.println("Longest Word: "+ longestWord);          // Final Output

    }
```

Comment: The question is about JavaScript, not Java.